# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. useEffect running infinitely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have been working on a react project and cannot solve this problem for the past 2 days. My fetch works properly and returns me a list of quizzes. But I cannot display them in the render for some reason. In the chrome devTools, I checked the state and it gets updated. I have tried passing in the response2.quizzes, newGames, games.concat(newGames) and all other possibilities into setGames. It won't work. Below is the code. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to react. Thank you

````
  const [games, setGames] = React.useState([]);
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const getListofGames = async () => {
    getMethodOptions.headers.Authorization = token
    const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/admin/quiz`, getMethodOptions);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const response2 = await response.json();
      const newGames = [];
      newGames.push(response2.quizzes);
      console.log(newGames);
      setGames([...newGames]);
    }
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getListofGames();
    console.log(games);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <CreateNewGameBar />
      <div>
        Create Games Appear here
      </div>
      {games.length > 0 && games.map(({id, name, thumbnail}) => (
        <QuizCard 
          quizId={id}
          quizName={name}
          thumbnail={thumbnail}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;```
````

Comment: Your useEffect will work only once during mount, are you sure the error is throwing from this piece of code?

Comment: I agree - I can't see how this would cause an infinite loop.